# where is link.h in the Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm

I am trying to compile a simple program using arm-linux-androideabi-g++. I am including this line im my program:

```
#include"link.h"
```

It gives error by saying **no such file or directory**. *When i tried searching for the file I could not find it*. I have searched the whole android-ndk directory and still could not find it. Can any one please help me find the file if there is any of its kind in the android ndk?

Or can i just use the `link.h` of `/usr/include/link.h` and modify it for Android somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Bohem GC, then you can use this link.h file, it works fine with Android: http://code.google.com/p/androidmono/source/browse/trunk/PlatformPatches/link.h

Comment: Thank you Martins it seems to work ... i let you know if i come accross problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a `.mk` file and set the path to the headers that you are using.

read this for reference:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-ndk/-_scQd5leqo

Comment: but there is no "link.h" file in the android-ndk at all :( .. and i am using cmake. i am looking into http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/64035/ i hope i might find answer .

Comment: NDK is a toolkit for native development, link.h is an header: what is the relation between them? Why are expecting to find link.h in the NDK directory? You should provide your code to the NDK and write the makefile in the right way, you don't have other options.

Comment: but i am using cmake and it look into CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH .. for the /usr/include of the android-ndk .. i surely cant use /usr/include of linux.